# Easy Way to Add Spaces to End of Text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a couple thousand rows of data and in column "A" the Item# appears. The item # can be from 2 to 12 characters long. I need an easy way to add spaces to the end of any item# so that each cell has 4 characters total. Is there a way to do this? For example I have Item # 3B or 4CWF. I need to add 2 spaces to # 3B and 0 spaces to 4CWF.

Thanks for any help.    i tried this but got error like #value! code is `=A1&REPT(" ",4-LEN(A1))`

```
|Cell A             |    Cell B                 
|-------------------|------------------------------------------|
|blue fractals      |blue fractals(need 2 spaces at end        |   
|-------------------|------------------------------------------|
|Red Pink Blue Cube |Cube Pink Blue Red(no space needed        |             
|-------------------|------------------------------------------|
|start text end     |text start end (one Space needed at end ) |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|
|words more then 4  |No space Needed at end of words           |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Your expression is correct, but it has to go in a different cell.

Comment: @AFH can you explain in which cell.

Comment: You would need to add a new column, eg set `B1` to `=A1&REPT(" ",12-LEN(A1))` and copy this expression down the rest of the column `B2` to `B2000`, or however long the first column is.

Comment: @AFH yes i do it same way but got same error , any other formula or way to do same thing

Comment: Your narrative says column I but your formula says column A.  Which column is it?

Comment: @ScottCraner yes , first i have values in I column but now i change it and all values in A column .

Comment: @ScottCraner - I assumed he had used column `A` for legibility.

Comment: The formula works fine for me, even when `A1` is empty.

Comment: I will bet that your data has more than 12 characters already in it.  Try this: `=LEFT(A1&REPT("-",12),12)` and see if you get your desired outcome with `-` at the end instead.  If no `-` appear then the data has more than 12 characters ans is why you are getting any error because REPT can not have a negative in the second criterion.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I was just testing overflow conditions when your comment appeared!

Comment: @ScottCraner i tried your formula now and i got ,  in Column A10 i have blue fractals  value and in Column B10 i got only blue word

Comment: You said your character count is 2 to 12 `blue fractals` is 13 characters and is why you are getting an error in your formula.  So please post some data and expected outcome.  Post your full strings longest and shortest.

Comment: @ScottCraner sorry dear , now update my question with new requirements , hope you understand and try to help .

Comment: @AFH sorry dear , please chk my updated question as my new requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IF(LEN(A2)<15,LEFT(A2&REPT(" ",15),15),A2)
```

[image]

Comment: @biz just an FYI: I realize that English is not your first language and I applaud your ability to speak multiple languages but `dear` is usually as a term of endearment between couples. It is also used by older ladies in the southeast part of the US when talking to those who are younger than them.

Comment: yes , ur right , and anyways thanks its work , appreciate your help .